# Loading a gmap immediately with a string address and not in latlng

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I want my Gmap will directly load from an `address string` and not a `latlng`. I know this is possible but I can't seem to figure it out. All the samples in the web load `latlng` as default and not `address string`.

Comment: What's the reasoning behind loading an address string directly, rather than making a call to convert it to a latlng then loading? Trying to reduce number of server calls?

Comment: @Tony, because the wrong tiles will start loading for the wrong map center! So it will be loading sloow and overload the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a complete address string then why dont you use google's Geocoder service to get lat lang then set the map co ordinates. this will ensure that your map will center the location given by string. Refer to [Geocoding Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)
for geocoding.